# How to create popup informations for mouseover

Tags: c#, popup, containers, mouseover, popupwindow

Please can you help me how can i create popup panel with informations for mouseover. I using C# offline application.

I don't know how can i do this on mouseover with application. For website it is javascript but for C# ... i don't know.

I know how to use mouseover for it, but i don't know how to create popup window with informations for mouseover. It's exactly my problem. Please can you help me?

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start by testing the following:

You can use `MouseEnter` to show a window in a popup style.

```
    private void panel1_MouseEnter(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
    {
        MyForm frm = new MyForm();
        frm.ShowDialog();
    }
```

When you require behavior like [jquery UI Tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) you can use [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
    private Control popup;

    private void panel1_MouseEnter(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
    {
        MyUserControl mcu = new MyUserControl ();
        this.popup =mcu; //save references to new control
        this.Controls.Add(this.popup);
        this.popup.Location.X = ((Control)sender).Location.X+ offsetX; 
        this.popup.Location.Y = ((Control)sender).Location.Y+ offsetY;


    }

    private void panel1_MouseLeave(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
    {
        this.Controls.Remove(this.popup);
    }
```

Comment: I testing now your solution

Comment: this.popup -. this send me errors that popup is not reference. And i searching references for it, but i havent Windows.Controls in list references.

Comment: No, you have to define it

Answer (score 0):

This sounds suspiciously like a ToolTip.
So I recommend that you use the ToolTipService for this (in your xaml):

```
<object>
  <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
    <objectThatFillsTheToolTip .../>
  </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</object>
```

This sample is from the [msdn docu page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltipservice%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Can you show me huge xaml script for it (any example)? Because i am newbie in this function.